# Java Generics extends still generates unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, unchecked

Is specifying the inheritance relation of parameterized generic types not enough to ensure type safety? For example:

```
public class ListCastFunction<F, T extends F> implements Function<F, T> {
    public final T apply(final F from) {
        return (T) from;
    }
}
```

This still generates a compiler warning. If we know `T extends F`, is it really unchecked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're casting and `F` to a `T`, but since `T extends F`, you're explicitly *downcasting*. There's no way to guarantee that the `F` given in the method is a `T`. Suppose I do this, assuming that the implied parent-child relationships are made:

```
ListCastFunction<Animal, Mammal> lcf = new ListCastFunction<>;
Mammal i = lcf.apply(new Fish());
```

This would break when executed, because a `Fish` is not a `Mammal`, but it fits your code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a explicitly require that the `F` given is a `T` without deliberately checking?

Comment: Use `T` in your declaration rather than `F`?

Comment: @CannonPalms the only way to guarantee that `F` is a `T` is if `F extends T` - and then you wouldn't need to cast - but you could also just use `new ArrayList<F>(listOfT)` too, with no need for `ListCastFunction`.